# How to override install4j internal compiler variables with maven-plugin?

Tags: install4j

Is it possible to override the standard compiler variables like `fullName` and `shortName` within the [sonatype-maven-plugin](http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) or commandline? The release tag matches for the version tag and we tried to define the `fullName` within the `variables` configuration of the plugin. This has no effect therefore the question whether it is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project, set the full name to a compiler variable like ${compiler:myFullName}. You can then override the compiler variable myFullName which will set the system variable.